# How do you create rect variables in python pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, pygame, rect

I am programming in Python with the `pygame` library. I want to know how to make a rectangle variable, something like:

```
import ...
rect1 = #RECT VARIABLE
rect2 = #RECT VARIABLE
```

Comment: A PyGame rect? `rect1 == pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)`. See this: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Comment: `import pygame`, `rect1 = pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)`, etc -- RTFM.

Comment: but how do you do when you blit the rect?

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)
```

this will return you a Rect object in pygame

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will work?

```
import pygame
# your whole code until you need a rectangle
rect1 = pygame.draw.rect( (x_coordinate, y_coordinate), (#a rgb color), (#size of rect in pixels) )
```

If you want a red rectangle with `100x150` size in `0x50` position, it will be:

```
rect1 = pygame.draw.rect( (0, 50), (255, 0, 0), (100, 150) )
```

To insert it into the screen you use:

```
pygame.screen_you_have_created.blit(rect1, 0, 50)
```

Answer (score -1):

For rectangle draw pattern is :  pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)

You can modify this code according to your need.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Title')
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
message =  'Hello '

text = basicFont.render(message, False, WHITE, BLUE)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
pixArray = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurface)
pixArray[480][380] = BLACK
del pixArray
windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: You've explained in your first line how to define a Rect but your code doesn't use this at all, instead you've used the `get_rect` method. That's just confusing. I think the two comments beneath the original question are more relevant.

Comment: So when you blit the rect, you don't supply coords?