# How do you create rect variables in pygame without drawing them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

What I want to do is assign a rect to a variable without drawing it on the screen. I was wondering how to do this. Here's my current code to assign a 20x20 white rectangle to "myRect":

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((50, 50))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    myRect  = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 20, 20))
```

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26831033/6220679 , but the answers there are bad, except for martineau's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Pygame.Rect:

```
myRect = pygame.Rect(20,20,100,200)    # 20 left, 20 top, 100 width, 200 height
```

See: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

> **pygame.Rect**
>   pygame object for storing rectangular coordinates
>      Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect
>      Rect((left, top), (width, height)) -> Rect
>      Rect(object) -> Rect

If you want to put a color on it as well, you could extend the Rect class.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought it would be something simple like that